# Multiselection in CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

I am creating a food app which requires recommendation. I am adding a feature which allows me to recommend particular food to my friends in my contact list. However, upon using CNContactViewController, I am not getting the required UI for multiselection. This is the screenshot of what I am getting
[image]

This looks quite messy. I don't want the cancel and group button. Is there any way to get what I am looking for? Any Custom way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As you asked to recommend other libraries, this could be the better option for multiselect design, check this->[EPContactsPicker](https://github.com/ipraba/EPContactsPicker)

**Update:**
For **multiselect** to enable in cncontactpicker, use this method **contactPicker:didSelectContacts:**

Comment: Tried using that library but they have a bug in their search functionality

Comment: Ther e is no issue with multiselect. The issue I am facing here is to modify the navigation bar which I dont thnk is possible by using the cncontactpicker. I need to find a custom way of achieving the kind of navigation bar I want to achieve